# How to post-process Spark SQL results w/o using UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I read

https://medium.com/teads-engineering/spark-performance-tuning-from-the-trenches-7cbde521cf60

It suggests not to use UDF to save deserialization/serialization cost.

In my case, I did a query like this

```
select MYFUN(f1, f2, ...) 
from A ...
```

I use MYFUN to post-process the query results row by row, for example, sending them to another service.

```
def my_fun(f1, f2, ...):
   service.send(f1, f2, ...)

session.udf.register('MYFUN', my_fun)
```

W/o using UDF, I may want to save the query results to a Python data frame, or a Parque table on hdfs then reading by a dataframe, and process the dataframe one by one.

The problem is the result table size is large, may be 1M rows.
In such a case, does it still make sense to remove the UDF?

What is the best practice to populate a Spark SQL result to another service?

Answer (score 1):

Python UDFs are not recommended from a performance point of view, but there is nothing wrong in using them when needed, as in this case: the serialization/deserialization cost is probably ridiculous compared to the I/O waits introduced by your `send`. So it probably doesn't make sense to remove the UDF.

In a more general case, there are two ways with which you can reduce the memory footprint of processing a dataframe. One you already mentioned, is save to file and process the file.

Another way is using [toLocalIterator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toLocalIterator) on your dataframe. This way you will iterate on each of the dataframe's partitions: you can repartition the dataframe to make partitions of an arbitrary size:

```
df =df.repartition(100)
for partition in df.toLocalIterator():
    for row in partition:
        send(row)
```

This way your local memory requirements are reduced to the biggest partition of your repartitioned dataframe.